# Oracle supported linux distributions

Tags: oracle, linux

According to this site (http://www.dbspecialists.com/oracle11glinux.html), Oracle is only supported on the following Linux distributions:

- Oracle Enterprise Linux
- Red Hat
- SUSE
- Asianux

Is there any technical reason that Oracle would perform poorly on a Debian-based install (Ubuntu)?  Or is this more about dealing with Oracle from an enterprise support standpoint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no reason why Oracle would perform badly on Ubuntu (though Oracles OEL kernel has some Oracle-specific optimisations), it's all about enterprise support.

Certification is an expensive and time-consuming task, as is training support workers in each flavour of Linux - that's why the RDBMS is only officially supported on a select number of releases.

Answer (score 4):

I have installed 11.2 on Ubuntu (in VMWARE) using this set of instructions:

[Oracle Database 11g Release 2 on Ubuntu 12.04 HOWTO](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906091827/http://hswong3i.net/blog/hswong3i/oracle-database-11g-release-2-ubuntu-12-04-howto)

I had to google a few other things, but in general this is by far the best set of instructions I have found. I recommend saving the website and keeping it in a safe place :)